# Checking and converting some value to number using conditional operator

Tags: javascript, numbers, conditional-operator

Given a string stored in a variable 'givenValue'. If it's all numbers, convert the string to number 
(e.g. '11' to 11, 'a1' to 'a1') 
and assign it to a variable 'value':

```
const value = givenValue - 0 === NaN ? givenValue : givenValue - 0;
```

But the output is not what I expected:

```
const givenValue = 'a1';
console.log(value); // NaN

const givenValue = '1';
console.log(value); // 1
```

Seems like the value of 'givenValue' is reassigned at the time of the 'if' condition being checked, or the condition check is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function to check something is `NaN` or not:

```
const givenValue = 'a1';
console.log(isNaN(givenValue) ? givenValue : +givenValue);
```

---

Also, if you want to check something is numeric or not before casting to a number, you can use `isNaN` function with [isFinite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) function:

```
const givenValue = 'a1';

const value = !isNaN(parseFloat(givenValue)) && isFinite(givenValue) 
              ? givenValue : +givenValue;

console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Strings that aren't fully numbers but have numeric characters [may well return a number](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type) other than `NaN` in many circumstances - see that link for a full description of how the algorithm works. Suffice to say, it's slightly complicated, and isn't what you're looking for. (eg, you'd want `'123e456'` to fail, but that'd actually give you `Infinity` instead. Whitespace will be permitted too.) (Also, a `=== NaN` check will always return `false`, because `NaN` isn't equal to anything)

Instead, use a regular expression to check that the string contains only digits:

```
const value = /^\d+$/.test(givenValue) ? Number(givenValue) : givenValue;
```

If you want to include possible decimal amounts too, then add an optional group of `.` followed by digits:

```
const value = /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(givenValue) ? Number(givenValue) : givenValue;
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Can you please explain me the `?:` part in your pattern?

Comment: That's an optional group of `.` followed by digits. Eg, it'll match the `.123` part of `1.123` - it matches a `.` followed by `\d+`, digits

Comment: Because I see that you have `?` follows by the group `(\.\d+)`, so I think we can remove it `?:`. The last `?` mean: everything inside the group can be zero or one time, right?

Comment: The `?:` at the beginning of the group makes it non-capturing. Capturing groups (denoted with just plain parentheses) should be used only when you need to capture the value - otherwise, better to use a non-capturing group, with `(?:`, to indicate to both the reader and the engine that the matched subpattern doesn't need to be saved or considered later.

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` doesn't equal itself. Try like this: `givenValue - 0 !== givenValue - 0 ? givenValue : givenValue - 0`.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, `NaN === NaN` is alway false.

So you should use `isNaN(givenValue - 0)` rather than `givenValue - 0 === NaN`

```js
console.log(NaN === NaN) // false
console.log(NaN == NaN) // false
console.log(isNaN(NaN)) // true

const fixedFunc = (givenValue) => isNaN(givenValue - 0) ? givenValue : givenValue - 0;

console.log(JSON.stringify({
  "fixedFunc('a1')": fixedFunc('a1'),
  "fixedFunc('1')": fixedFunc('1')
}))
```

Answer (score -1):

**ONLY WORKS WITH NONZERO NUMBERS**

A simpler method would be to use `const value = givenValue - 0 || givenValue;`

```js
var givenValue = '1';
var value = givenValue - 0 || givenValue;
console.log(value);

givenValue = 'a1';
value = givenValue - 0 || givenValue;
console.log(value);
```